# iOS Local Notifications vs Remote

Tags: ios, swift3, push-notification

I am currently working on an app which has a "Blog-reader" section. I want to send notifications whenever there is a new post in the backend which is set up using Firebase.

At this point I have setup the remote notifications in AppDelegate and everything works just fine with a few caveats:

The app does not have a authentication / user profiles so whenever I receive a notification from Firebase with a badge payload set to "1" the app always displays 1 badge regardless of how many new posts are there. I have really no idea how to store somehow the badges locally and then append the count whenever there is a new notification.

Given the knowledge-related issue above I was thinking of using local notifications and displaying badges based on the count of how many items posts objects array has in it and compare it to the previous stored value.

I have a gut feeling that this might not be the best solution at all, unfortunately this is my first ever iOS / Swift project (and real app ever built).

So, in a nutshell, does anyone have any suggestions if my proposed local notifications approach is a good idea, otherwise how do I handle the "badge count" from Firebae if I do not have user profiles?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Best regards,

Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle this one from server side one from app side

1:Server side
From server side they need to handle unread notification count while sending push notification they need to send unread notification value `badge` this is only possible if server side they are handle read and unread notification status

2:App side
you need to store your unread notification count in UserDefaults based on receiving and read notification you need to change that count and you can assign that unread notification count value like below

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = unreadCount //instead of unreadCount pass you unread notification count value that should be Int
```